# There is not PhoneGap.plist in my Phonegap-Project

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

Starting working with phonegap on a mac (Xcode 4, building an iphone application) I've read a lot about a file called `phonegap.plist`, including whitelisting of external Urls and something else.

This is my question, I can not find such a file in the `phonegap-project` in my xcode 4 project. There is a file named by `cordova.plist`, and a file `project-name.plist` (where project-name indicates the real name of the project). But there is no file with the name called `phonegap.plist`.

I tried the search of Xcode, i tried `find / -iname 'phonegap.plist'`

Where is my error in reasoning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhoneGap.plist has been renamed Cordova.plist.

Comment: If that's missing, try config.xml

Answer (score 2):

Since PhoneGap upgraded, the Cordova.plist file was discontinued and is instead config.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  try config.xml you can find the plugins there..